# Mac - VSCode - Converting Python File to PDF Error

Tags: python, pdf, visual-studio-code, jupyter

After pip3 installing nbconvert and jupyter and installing MacTex, I still have the following error, which wouldnt allow me to export to PDF:
Could anyone provide assistance? Thank you

[image]

Comment: Please post the output as text!

Comment: @Klaus I have tried that but it has a weird format output as visual... so i made a ss for better view.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export it to HTML and then using the `Print to PDF` feature of your browser like the message suggested.

If you insist to export it to `PDF` directly. After you install the `MacTex` you need to restart your computer, and make sure the installation path of `MacTex` can be found in your VSCode terminal, `xelatex` command can be recognized. Like this picture displays(Windows):

[image]